# create an associative array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

This is what I have so far and the *shoe types* are `boots, wellingtons, leather, trainers (in that order)`

I want to iterate through and assign the value so I haves something like

```
var shoeArray = { boots : '3', wellingtons: '0', leather : '1', trainers: '3'};
```

at the moment I just get an array of `{3,0,1,3}` which I can work with but it is not very helpful.

```
function shoe_types() {
    var shoeArray = [];
    $('[type=number]').each(function(){
        $('span[data-field='+$(this).attr('id')+']').text($(this).val());      
        shoeArray.push ( parseInt($(this).val()) );      
    });             
    return shoeArray;        
}
```

Comment: There are no "associative arrays" in JS. You're talking about objects. Some reading material: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: the shoe types are fixed - there is only and will only be the 4 types

Comment: @Roscoeh i think `$(this).attr('id')` has shoe types

Comment: An array in JavaScript would be represented as `[3,0,1,3]`, not `{3,0,1,3}`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check this function

```
function shoe_types() {
    var shoeArray = {}; // note this
    $('[type=number]').each(function(){
       $('span[data-field='+$(this).attr('id')+']').text($(this).val());
       shoeArray[$(this).attr('id')] =  parseInt($(this).val()) ;
    });
    return shoeArray;

}
```

PS: Assuming `$(this).attr('id')` has all the shoe types

Answer (score 11):

Associative array in javascript is the same as object

Example:

```
var a = {};
a["name"] = 12;
a["description"] = "description parameter";
console.log(a); // Object {name: 12, description: "description parameter"}

var b = [];
b["name"] = 12;
b["description"] = "description parameter";
console.log(b); // [name: 12, description: "description parameter"]
```

Comment: Did you mean to use curly brackets for var b?

Comment: i don't think so @Mark

Answer (score 7):

What you want is a function that will return an **object** `{}`

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OMulakE/1/edit)**

```
function shoe_types(){
   var shoeObj = {};
   $('[name="number"]').each(function(){
     shoeObj[this.id] = this.value;
   });
   return shoeObj;
}

shoe_types(); // [object Object]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to create an associate array in jquery

```
var arr = {};
$('[type=number]').each(function(){
    arr.push({
         $(this).attr('id'): $(this).val()              
     });
});

console.log(arr);
```

This will allow you to send your all data whatever you want to pass in array by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

if `$(this).attr('id')` is the type of shoes you can try that

```
shoeArray[$(this).attr('id')] = parseInt($(this).val());
```